# Having 403 error while uploading file to sharepoint using RestAPI

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to upload a file to my sharepoint folder using RestAPI but everytime i received status code 403 forbidden. As i am implementing this in dot net core console application so i need to use RestAPI because of "SharePointOnlineCredentials" is no more supported in core. Any help would be much appreciated. Below i pasted my existing code .Thanks !!

```
            byte[] bytefile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:/4.txt");
            string hostWeb = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxProjects";
            HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(hostWeb + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/xxx/Shared%20Documents/Folder1')/Files/add(url='4.txt',overwrite=true)");
            endpointRequest.Method = "POST";                
            endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/json";               
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            endpointRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(bytefile, 0, bytefile.Length);
            HttpWebResponse endpointresponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP Core to upload files to SharePoint. Check this link on how to do it with PnP Core.

https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/files-intro.html#adding-files-uploading